# Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Exchange - meaning of error 80041194?

Tags: exchange, migration, google-workspace, exchange-2007

Google Apps Migration for Microsoft Exchange (aka GAMME) works a treat - ALMOST.

I am getting multiple occurrences of error 80041194 in the log but there is no further description and searching the web on this reveals basically nothing.

https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Apps+Migration+for+Microsoft+Exchange+error+80041194

https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Apps+Migration+for+Microsoft+Exchange+error%3A80041194

Does anyone know what this error means?

Surely Google should document all errors for such a critical tool in their drive to unseat Microsoft!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, I was also Googling this error and was frustrated to only find this unanswered forum post.

Then, I clicked to view the error report at the end of the tool (good comprehensive overview of the success/failure status) and learned that it means this:

Reason: GMail has a 25MB message limit and messages larger than this limit will not be uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

I encounter the same error and find this page: http://www.classthink.com/forums/topic/gamme-gmail-migration-error-8004106b/
In brief:
Error:8004106b will be generated under the following circumstances:

- The message being migrated contains an attachment which is not
  acceptable to GMail — for example a .exe or .zip file.
- The message is considered spam by GMail.
- The message contains an attachment which is over GMail’s 25MB limit.
- The message plus the attachment is larger than 34MB.
- Exchange has failed to correctly convert the email to the format
  required by the GAMME tool.
- The message is corrupt.